# For loop array confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Im working in a class and the built in editor is telling me this funtion returns "a", but i expected it to return "a","b","c","d". Can someone please explain what im not understanding here ?

```
    function chunk(arr) {

  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
  return arr[i];

}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);``
```

Comment: return ends the function and the loop.

Comment: "Im working in a class ..." Don't you have a teacher there?

Comment: its one of those free online code camps

Comment: i was not aware that return ended the loop. Thanks for the info. I thought that might be what was happening wasnt 100%

Answer (score 1):

A function can only have one return value, so the code ends when the `return` is executed the first time. The `return` statement is defined to exit the function immediately.

The return value can however be an array (or an object), so if you want to return multiple values you can put them in an array:

```
function chunk(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(arr[i] + '!');
  }
  return result;
}

var values = chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);

// values now contain ['a!', 'b!', 'c!', 'd!']
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns 'a' because the return statement itself is returning a specific item in the array

```
return arr[i];//in example above, i is 0
          ^^^
```

Imagine the array structured like

```
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
3 -> d
4 -> e
```

So, when you access with index `0`, `a` is returned.

To return the whole array, do so without index

```
return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning too early:

```
function chunk(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method, which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
It's more clean.

So just do :

```
  function chunk(arr) {
    //Map our array and return a new array
    return arr.map(function(elm){
      return elm;
    });

  };

  var a = chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);

  console.log(a);
  //Print ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```